# Is there any node library to rename files in gridfs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to know if there any node module or document on node module to rename filename or file metadata in gridFs.

I went through lot of module and their examples nothing helped, can someone give input on this?

Current file content in Mongoose/Mongo DB.

```
gfs.files.find({ filename: 'mongo_file_1.txt' }).toArray(function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
                 throw (err);
        }
        console.log(files);
  });

Ouput :
{ _id: 5a7ae0fd9a86e52eba301cbb,
    filename: 'mongo_file_1.txt',
    contentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
    length: 288,
    chunkSize: 261120,
    uploadDate: Wed Feb 07 2018 16:50:31 GMT+0530 (IST),
    aliases: null,
    metadata: { version: 1 },
    md5: '472c1a81dcdbce9b8f20bf98de238dbb' },
```

I wanted to know if I can either change filename or version number in metadata.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to edit the metadata by accessing the underlying Mongo collection that is backing your gridfs files.

See what Mongo collections the gridfs uses:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-collections

In particular, see the `files` collection that stores the metadata:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs-files-collection

Thos are Mongo collections that you should be able to modify yourself but **be careful** because modifying the metadata yourself you might potentially change something like the md5 checksum etc.

See this issue comments for some more info:

- https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/issues/35

(it's about `gridfs-stream` module the answers are general)